# How to fill NaN will last value?

Tags: pandas

For example:

```
arr = ['a', np.nan, np.nan, 'b', np.nan, 'a', np.nan, np.nan]
```

let's say i want to forward fill so i get `['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a']`

I have tried using `fillna(method='ffill)`, but this just fills with a static value ie. 0. I don't see an option to use last-valid value.

If i use `ffill()` which works for when my array has one non-nan value. But when i use for an array with various values, it looks like nothing changes in the column.

I wanted to forward fill with the last non-nan value. How do i do this?

Comment: `ffill()` is indeed what you're looking for. Did you try `pd.Series(arr).ffill()`?

Comment: It looks like pandas was converting my nan values into string 'nan'. For example i have a line of code df['last_event'] = np.select([(df['valley']), (df['peak'])], ['valley', 'peak'], default=np.nan). Even though i have default set to np.nan, when i view my data it is showing as 'nan'. How can i stop this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`ffill` is the function you need, maybe you just forget to specify inplace=True